# FAQ/Reputation info images are low quality

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

Various images from the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) and [privilege info](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges) pages are either low quality, outdated, or simply incorrect. For example, this image is of especially low quality:

[image]

Sure, it's not a huge problem, but it's an annoyance. These would be easy to fix with newer images specific to SE Gaming, like so:

[image]

Call it a pet peeve, but it just seems rather silly to have these things when the rest of the site is so professional.

## Update

As an update to this, it appears that the various images are *not* cross-site, since [SO-Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) has my updated image, but [we don't](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user). (If you think about it, that's pretty odd, since the image is SE Gaming themed, but whatever.)

Additionally, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107762/pictures-on-the-established-user-privilege-page-are-a-little-messed-up/107765#107765) on Meta Stack Overflow claims that the pages are community content and can be edited. While I don't appear to have the privileges to edit them, I'm sure some people do.

I propose we all try to create some new SE Gaming-specific images to replace the old inferior ones. If they are well-received, someone should edit them in. Who's with me?

Comment: These images are used [everywhere](http://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user) I believe, so we might need to migrate this to the system-wide meta.

Comment: Related: [Pictures on the Established User privilege page are a little messed up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com//107762/154510).  I'm unsure about the FAQ but the privilege pages, at least, can be edited.  I never got around to doing it myself.

Comment: @agent86 Can I get an official confirmation that those are cross-site? If they are (and I believe you), then perhaps we can at least get some nicer images system-wide.

Comment: @MatthewRead, was that perhaps deleted?  I guess I don't have sufficient meta-rep to see it.

Comment: @agent86 Looks like I accidentally deleted one character from the URL.  Here we go: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107762/pictures-on-the-established-user-privilege-page-are-a-little-messed-up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107762/pictures-on-the-established-user-privilege-page-are-a-little-messed-up)

Comment: Privilege wikis *are* pulled from MSO, but a) you need a certain amount of rep to edit them (2k I believe), and b) [it's not automated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110233/privilege-page-updates-not-being-pushed-to-the-rest-of-the-network/110241#110241). I'm not sure Gaming-specific images are appropriate; Stack Overflow is the biggest SE site by one or two orders of magnitude, and Sketchy is the default design for new sites.

Comment: @lunboks [Not anymore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/). :) But yeah, we might need to update various screenshots that still refer to Sketchy.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The old FAQ was replaced with the much upgraded [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), and the site's design was updated to a '[unified theme](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182)' with the rest of the network, which standardised a bunch of things, including the voting buttons and vote count positions.